# How to set the selected list item as completely visible in android list view?

Tags: android, listview, listitem, setfocus

I have a simple onclick listener. On click of any list item, I have to make that list item completely visible. 
For example I have 10 items in list view, if I click the 10th item which is partially visible, the complete list item should get displayed to the user.
I have tried with the following options. But its not working as expected. Could anyone please share your suggestions to acheive the same.

```
            v.setFocusable(true);
            ......................

            if(!v.isFocused()){
                v.setFocusable(true);
            }
            .......................
```

Comment: Is this an `onClickListener` or `onItemClickListener()`

Comment: Hi this is onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the following code snippet. It's working fine for me.

```
    public static void setSelectedListItemVisible(int position) {

    myListView.setSelection(position);

    }
```

I called this function inside my onClickListener.